# Exception during the execution of microsoft partner portal project

Tags: c#, ms-project

I have the code of the microsoft project partner portal. When I execute the code (pressing f5) and the project load I get the exception

> The entity with a name = 'adx_website' was not found in the MetadataCache.

I change the webservice url of the dynamic crm to a local one.
Maybe I have to execute the project in the same server of the crm.